# Why can't I see bookmarks in another word document when trying to create a bookmark based hyperlink?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, bookmarks, table-of-contents

So the document I have already has headings and a table of contents (TOC) and thus it has bookmarks

However I need to link to this document from elsewhere but when I go to the other document and 'create hyperlink', add in the http doc location, then click on 'bookmarks'

It is blank, yet I know they exist

Comment: If it only has the bookmarks generated by the ToC, they are invisible (their names start with "_", and I do not think they will appar in any list. Headings do not have bookmarks just because they are headings - only if the ToC generated them, or you inserted them, or (for example) you selected the heading and did an Edit copy/Edite Paste Special.